# Can MPI gather, reduce, send, or receive Fortran derived types?

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, derived-types

I want to copy a derived type xyzBuffer from processor 1 to xyz of processor 0. I attempted MPI_GATHER with:

```
 call MPI_GATHERV(xyzBuffer,1,inewtype,xyz,1, dispGather,inewtype,0,icomm,ierr)
```

But processor 0 will have memory bits not written to: it seems that MPI_GATHER does not allow the gather of derived types. I used MPI_ISEND/MPI_IRECV, but the program hangs at the following line of code:

```
 if ( iproc == 1 ) then
       call MPI_ISEND(xyz,1,inewtype,1,itag,icomm,ireq,ierr)
       call MPI_WAIT(ireq,istatus,ierr)
    else if ( iproc == 0 ) then 
       call MPI_IRECV(xyz,1,inewtype,0,itag,icomm,ireq,ierr)
       call MPI_WAIT(ireq,istatus,ierr)
    end if
```

Are these methods not meant to be used with derived types?

Below is the full program. I comment out MPI_GATHER when testing MPI_ISEND, MPI_IRECV block, and vice-versa.

```
program type_derived_gather
  use nodeinfo
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer(4) :: ierr
  integer(4) :: istatus(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  integer(4) :: i
  integer(4) :: j
  integer(4) :: iblock(8)
  integer(4) :: idisp(8)
  integer(4) :: itype(8)
  integer(4) :: inewtype
  integer(4) :: iextent
  integer(4) :: itag
  integer(4) :: ireq, isend, irecv
  integer(4) :: dispGather ! for root

    TYPE :: newXYZ
        integer :: x, u
        integer :: y, v
        integer :: z, w
        integer,dimension(3) :: uvw     
    END TYPE

    TYPE (newXYZ) :: xyzBuffer
    TYPE (newXYZ) :: xyz


  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  icomm = MPI_COMM_WORLD
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(icomm,nproc,ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(icomm,iproc,ierr)


    if (iproc == 1) then
        xyz%x = 1
        xyz%y = 2
        xyz%z = 3
        xyz%u = 4
        xyz%v = 5
        xyz%w = 6
        xyz%uvw = (/10,10,10/)
    else
        xyz%x = 0
        xyz%y = 0       
        xyz%z = 0
        xyz%u = 0
        xyz%v = 0       
        xyz%w = 0 
        xyz%uvw = (/0,0,0/)
    endif


! Derived type
  iblock(1) = 1
  iblock(2) = 1
  iblock(3) = 1
  iblock(4) = 1
  iblock(5) = 1
  iblock(6) = 1
  iblock(7) = 3
  iblock(8) = 1

  idisp(1)  = 0  ! in bytes
  idisp(2)  = 4*1  ! in bytes
  idisp(3)  = 4*2  ! in bytes 
  idisp(4)  = 4*3  ! in bytes 
  idisp(5)  = 4*4  ! in bytes
  idisp(6)  = 4*5  ! in bytes 
  idisp(7)  = 4*6  ! in bytes 
  idisp(8)  = 4*9  ! in bytes    

  itype(1)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(2)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(3)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(4)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(5)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(6)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(7)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(8)  = MPI_UB  
  call MPI_TYPE_STRUCT(8,iblock,idisp,itype,inewtype,ierr)
  call MPI_TYPE_EXTENT(inewtype,iextent,ierr)
  write(6,*)'newtype extent = ',iextent  
  call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(inewtype,ierr)

    itag = 1
    dispGather = 0


  do j = 1, 2
     if ( j == 2 ) then
! Gather
        call MPI_GATHERV(xyzBuffer,1,inewtype,xyz,1, dispGather,inewtype,0,icomm,ierr)
! Isend Irecv 
        if ( iproc == 1 ) then
           call MPI_ISEND(xyz,1,inewtype,1,itag,icomm,isend,ierr)
           write(6,*)'end send'
           call MPI_WAIT(isend,istatus,ierr)
        else if ( iproc == 0 ) then
           call MPI_IRECV(xyz,1,inewtype,0,itag,icomm,irecv,ierr)
           write(6,*)'end receive'
           call MPI_WAIT(irecv,istatus,ierr)
        end if
! Output 
     end if      
     call MPI_BARRIER(icomm,ierr)
     if ( iproc == 0 )write(6,*)'iproc = ',iproc
        if ( iproc == 0 ) write(6,*)xyz

     call MPI_BARRIER(icomm,ierr)
     if ( iproc == 1 )write(6,*)'iproc = ',iproc
        if ( iproc == 1 ) write(6,*)xyz
  end do

  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end program type_derived_gather
```

When I run with MPI_ISEND and MPI_IRECV block, the program hangs and the ouput is:

```
 iproc =            0
           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
 end receive
 newtype extent =           36
 iproc =            1
           1           4           2           5           3           6          10          10          10
 end send
```

When MPI_GATHER runs, I receive a Segmentation Fault with output:

```
 newtype extent =           36
 iproc =            0
           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
 newtype extent =           36
 iproc =            1
           1           4           2           5           3           6          10          10          10
 newtype extent =           36
 newtype extent =           36
 newtype extent =           36
 newtype extent =           36
 newtype extent =           36
 newtype extent =           36
[west0302:17101] *** Process received signal ***
[west0302:17101] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[west0302:17101] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[west0302:17101] Failing at address: 0x7ff2c8d1ddc0
[west0302:17101] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3d3540eb70]
[west0302:17101] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(memcpy+0xe1) [0x3d3487c321]
[west0302:17101] [ 2] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib64/libmpi.so.0(ompi_convertor_unpack+0x153) [0x2acd5f392093]
[west0302:17101] [ 3] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv_request_progress+0x7d1) [0x2acd6423dd91]
[west0302:17101] [ 4] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so [0x2acd6423a4c7]
[west0302:17101] [ 5] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_sm.so(mca_btl_sm_component_progress+0xde2) [0x2acd64ca81c2]
[west0302:17101] [ 6] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib/openmpi/mca_bml_r2.so(mca_bml_r2_progress+0x2a) [0x2acd6444504a]
[west0302:17101] [ 7] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib64/libopen-pal.so.0(opal_progress+0x4a) [0x2acd5f84a9ba]
[west0302:17101] [ 8] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so(mca_pml_ob1_recv+0x2b5) [0x2acd64238565]
[west0302:17101] [ 9] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_basic.so(mca_coll_basic_gatherv_intra+0x14a) [0x2acd650bb37a]
[west0302:17101] [10] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib64/libmpi.so.0(MPI_Gatherv+0x1b0) [0x2acd5f3a4170]
[west0302:17101] [11] /n/sw/openmpi-1.2.5-gcc-4.1.2/lib64/libmpi_f77.so.0(mpi_gatherv__+0x134) [0x2acd5f142784]
[west0302:17101] [12] ./type_derived_gather.x(MAIN__+0x342) [0x401742]
[west0302:17101] [13] ./type_derived_gather.x(main+0xe) [0x403fee]
[west0302:17101] [14] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4) [0x3d3481d994]
[west0302:17101] [15] ./type_derived_gather.x [0x401349]
[west0302:17101] *** End of error message ***
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What do you mean with generation, and do you want the data to be distributed? Anyway, the answer is probably yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can certainly do this: the problem with your code hanging on the `MPI_Isend()`/`MPI_Irecv()` is that you're sending to/receiving from the wrong process; you want 1 to send to 0, and 0 to send to 1, not 1 to send to 1 and 0 to receive from 0.  0 is never receiving that phantom message (since it doesn't exist), and you're hanging.

```
    if ( iproc == 1 ) then
       call MPI_ISEND(xyz,1,inewtype,1,itag,icomm,isend,ierr)
       write(6,*)'end send'
       call MPI_WAIT(isend,istatus,ierr)
    else if ( iproc == 0 ) then
       call MPI_IRECV(xyz,1,inewtype,0,itag,icomm,irecv,ierr)
       write(6,*)'end receive'
       call MPI_WAIT(irecv,istatus,ierr)
    end if
```

should be

```
    if ( iproc == 1 ) then
       call MPI_ISEND(xyz,1,inewtype,0,itag,icomm,isend,ierr)
       call MPI_WAIT(isend,istatus,ierr)
    else if ( iproc == 0 ) then
       call MPI_IRECV(xyz,1,inewtype,1,itag,icomm,irecv,ierr)
       call MPI_WAIT(irecv,istatus,ierr)
    end if
```

As to the larger question, it's certainly possible to use `MPI_Type_create_struct()` (note, you should use this newer routine rather than `MPI_Create_struct()` on Fortran derived data types.  As @elorenz points out, though, calculating the offsets by hand is not only tedious and error-prone, but likely incorrect; the compiler has a lot of freedom to pad, etc, for efficient memory access.   In your case, it likely will work since it's all integers, but for types with fields of mixed sizes, you will get into trouble.

The correct way to deal with that is to use `MPI_Get_address` to calculate the field offsets for you; below is a full example.

```
program type_derived_gather
  use iso_fortran_env
  use mpi
  implicit none
  integer :: ierr
  integer, parameter :: nfields=4
  integer :: iblock(nfields)
  integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: start, idisp(nfields)
  integer :: itype(nfields)
  integer :: inewtype
  integer :: nproc, iproc
  integer :: i

  type :: newXYZ
       integer :: id
       real(kind=real64) :: x, y, z
  end type

  type(newXYZ), dimension(:), allocatable :: allxyzs
  type(newXYZ) :: locxyz

  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,nproc,ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,iproc,ierr)

  locxyz % x  = 1.d0*iproc
  locxyz % y  = 2.d0*iproc
  locxyz % z  = 3.d0*iproc
  locxyz % id = iproc

  if (iproc == 0) allocate(allxyzs(nproc))

  ! everyone builds the type

  iblock = 1

  itype(1)  = MPI_INTEGER
  itype(2:4)= MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION

  call MPI_Get_address(locxyz,    start, ierr)
  call MPI_Get_address(locxyz%id, idisp(1), ierr)
  call MPI_Get_address(locxyz%x,  idisp(2), ierr)
  call MPI_Get_address(locxyz%y,  idisp(3), ierr)
  call MPI_Get_address(locxyz%z,  idisp(4), ierr)

  idisp = idisp - start

  call MPI_Type_create_struct(nfields,iblock,idisp,itype,inewtype,ierr)
  call MPI_Type_commit(inewtype,ierr)

  ! Now gather the structs

  print '(A,I3,A,I3,1X,3(F6.2,1X))', 'Rank ', iproc, ': locxyz = ', locxyz%id, locxyz%x, locxyz%y, locxyz%z

  call MPI_Gather(locxyz, 1, inewtype, allxyzs, 1, inewtype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

  if (iproc == 0) then
      print '(A,I3,A)', 'Rank ', iproc, ' has -- '
      do i=1, nproc
          print '(A,I3,A,I3,1X,3(F6.2,1X))', '    ', i, ': ', allxyzs(i)%id, allxyzs(i)%x, allxyzs(i)%y, allxyzs(i)%z
      enddo
      deallocate(allxyzs)
  end if

  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end program type_derived_gather
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use MPI_Gather (or other collectives) with derived datatypes. Any MPI function that takes a MPI_Datatype argument can be used with derived datatypes. If you post a minimal example how you construct and use a derived datatype we can probably help much better.

Comment: Thank you, the program is posted. I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. But make sure you use "sequence" in the definition of your data type! Otherwise the compiler is able to take some freedom in how type members are aligned in memory. And that might lead to some scrambled data when copying buffers.